# What is the Java equivalent of C's printf %g format specifier?

Tags: java, c, printf, formatter

I tried using Formatter.format, but that seems to leave the mantissa on numbers with 0 mantissa, whereas the C version does not. Is there an equivalent of C's %g format specifier in Java, and if not, is there a way to fake it? My intention is to preserve the mantissa exactly like C's for compatibility reasons.

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%g\n", 1.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Main.java

```
class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.printf("%g\n", 1.0);
        }
}
```

Console:

```
$ javac Main.java && java Main
1.00000
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out
1
```

Similarly, with 1.2 as input, the mantissa is longer in Java's version

```
$ javac Main.java && java Main
1.20000
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out
1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class?

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat().format(1.0));
```

outputs:

```
1
```

whereas:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat().format(1.2));
```

outputs:

```
1.2
```

Comment: Why is this accepted? DecimalFormat does not appear to provide the `%g` functionality of choosing the shorter of `%e` or `%f`.

Answer (score 4):

**edit**:
This code causes the fractional part to go missing if the exponent is 17 digits, because of my misunderstanding of how String.format formatted those numbers. So don't please don't use this code :P

Thanks for the input, guys. I couldn't find a way to configure DecimalFormat or NumberFormat to exactly clone the functionality, but it seems this method works (followed by an example):

```
String.format("%.17g", x).replaceFirst("\\.?0+(e|$)", "$1");
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, -0.0);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 0.0);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 1.0);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 1.2);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 0.0000000123456789);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 1234567890000000.0);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 0.0000000123456789012345678);
    printf("%.*g\n", 17, 1234567890123456780000000.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Main.java

```
class Main {
        public static String formatDouble(double x) {
                return String.format("%.17g", x).replaceFirst("\\.?0+(e|$)", "$1");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(formatDouble(-0.0));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(0.0));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(1.0));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(1.2));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(0.0000000123456789));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(1234567890000000.0));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(0.0000000123456789012345678));
                System.out.println(formatDouble(1234567890123456780000000.0));
        }
}
```

and their outputs:

```
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out
-0
0
1
1.2
1.23456789e-08
1234567890000000
1.2345678901234567e-08
1.2345678901234568e+24
$ javac Main.java && java Main
-0
0
1
1.2
1.23456789e-08
1234567890000000
1.2345678901234567e-08
1.2345678901234568e+24
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [NumberFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). By setting the minimum fraction digits to 0, but leaving the maximum bigger, it should do what you want.

It's not as easy as printf, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can specify how many digits you want: "%.2g" will display 1.2 as 1.20

Comment: the problem is that will truncate the mantissa if it has more than 2 digits. I didn't say it in the question, but my intention is to preserve the mantissa exactly like C's for compatibility reasons. As far as I can tell, C's %g will put as many digits in the mantissa as necessary but no more.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using

```
String.format("%.17g", x).replaceFirst("\\.?0+(e|$)", "$1")
```

fails for 1.2345e-20 (strips the zero from the end, producing 1.2345e-2).
Here is what I ended up using in my code:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%.6g", x).replaceFirst("\\.0+(e|$)", "$1").replaceFirst("(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])(0+)(e|$)", "$1$3")
```

Basically I modified the expression to ensure only zeros at the end of the fractional part are removed and split this into two cases. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions are prefect.  There are quite a few issues here and there in certain cases.  So I created a small library Double2String to address this specific issue:

https://github.com/coconut2015/double2string