# C fprintf %g correspondence in Scala/Java

Tags: c, scala, printf

I have to automatically compare text output from a C program and a conversion to Scala. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to format `double` values the same way. In C I have for example:

```
double diff = -1.0;  // just an example
fprintf(stdout, "diff %g\n", diff);
```

This is written as

```
diff -1
```

(no decimal point).

In Scala I have

```
val diff = -1.0;  // just an example
println(f"diff $diff%g\n")
```

This is written as

```
diff -1.00000
```

In other words, the `%g` formatter doesn't do the same. I am looking [at this document](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm), but can't a way to have 100% compatible `fprintf` format.

---

**Edit**: [*Without using JNI or writing page long special methods.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749802/c-compatible-printf-output-for-java)

Comment: I doubt it would take a "page-long special method" to post-process the Java Formatter output to conform to your requirements.

Comment: I dont see a 100% correspondence between C and Java string formatters. Thanks for this question anyways :-)

Answer (score 1):

Scala uses the the Java Formatter class documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). To get what you want:

```
scala> "%.0g".format(-1.0)
res0: String = -1
```

Comment: I guess @0__ wants to get `-1.1` on `"%.0g".format(-1.1)`

Comment: I just went over the JavaDoc and I don't see a way to get that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so [this is an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873298/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-cs-printf-g-format-specifier) with a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873298/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-cs-printf-g-format-specifier#873462) by @john-douthat, which needs some tiny adjustments:

```
def ¬(x: Double) = {
  val obj = x.toFloat.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
  String.format("%.6g", obj).replaceFirst("\\.?0+(e|$)", "$1")
}

val diff = -1.0
println(s"diff ${¬(diff)}")
println(s"Pi ${¬(math.Pi)}")
```

Output:

```
diff -1
Pi 3.14159
```

There are still some problems, though. For example `-3.59847e-10` gets output as `-3.59847e-1`. This is bug in the regexp for `replaceFirst`. If someone can fix it better than this, I'd be very happy (regexps have a mental mismatch with me):

```
def ¬(x: Double) = {
  val obj = x.toFloat.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
  val s0  = String.format("%.6g", obj)
  val i0  = s0.lastIndexOf('e')
  val i   = if (i0 < 0) s0.length else i0
  s0.substring(0, i).replaceFirst("\\.?0+($)", "$1") + s0.substring(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
  val diff = -1.0               //> diff  : Double = -1.0
  "diff %g\n".format(diff)      //> res6: String = "diff -1.00000
                                //| "
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, question amended. Anyway, very different from the C output.